# Block a certain website using java

Tags: java

I'm working on a small (i hope so) project and I'm in a very begginning. I've googled around and still couldn't get started. Let me explain my idea. First I type a website's address (let say codeproject.com) in a JTextField. Then after hitting on a JButton (let say Block), I can't open that site using internet browser (firefox actually). But after hitting another JButton (let say Unblock), I can normally access the website. I've just known that it's difficult to do this using java. Using C++ is maybe a better choice.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you working on your own HTTP proxy or something like that?

Comment: This has less to do with Java o C++ but on the underlying system. Do you basically want to add and remove entries in your firewall? Which system?

Comment: @ Moritz Petersen: well, actually I've no idea if I'm working on HTTP proxy. What I expect is to see how powerful Java can do in this case?

Comment: @Matteo: My system is windows 7 and I assume that I don't have any firewall working on my system, even the windows 7's firewall.

Comment: @TrinhDuyHung Again: this has nothing to do with Java or powerful it is. You have either: to instruct your browser to use a proxy you control or change the firewall settings with your Java program.

Comment: @Matteo: I think changing the firewall settings with my Java program is good choice if it really helps. Could you get me started?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Rabbit](http://www.khelekore.org/rabbit/), which is a proxy server written in Java. Of course, your browser must be configured to pass all requests through that proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with @Moritz Petersen I can suggest yet another solution. HTTP proxy is fine but user can remove it from preferences of his browser. But you can probably do something else. [JPcap](http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/) is a library for capturing and *sending* network packets.

So, your application can do the following: capture HTTP request sent from any browser on the machine. If requested URL matches one from your black list send "reject" to the browser back after a small delay. So, from user perspective it will look like the browser is starting rendering the requested site and suddenly reject page appears. This is more complicated than using ready HTTP proxy but very IMHO interesting and should be relatively small project. And user cannot bypass your check unless he kills your application.

Comment: @AlexR Let say that I can capture any HTTP request sent from any browser on my machine. If requested URL matches one from my black list, so how could I send "reject" to the browser to prevent it to access the URL?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a proxy server, then you're software has to be running all the time. Instead, for an entry level website access control software, you can use java or c++ to build an application(GUI). The software has to just edit the 'hosts' in your OS and the WebDomain shall be blocked.

Location of 'hosts' file:

- In Windows: **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts**
- In Linux: **/etc/hosts**

You software shall need administrator/root privileges to edit the 'hosts' file.

**Steps to Initiate your software:**

- Edit the file and remove the '#' before the lines

--- 127.0.0.1       localhost

--- ::1             localhost

**Steps to Block a Website:**

- Append the below line to the 'hosts' file:

--- 0.0.0.0   www.facebook.com

--- 0.0.0.0   www.example.com

**Steps to Unblock:**

- Just remove the line that you've added to the file.

**CAUTION:**

Never erase the file contents which are there by default. Maintaining a backup copy of 'hosts' file is recommended.